# Gradle error when trying to build Android Things project with Android Studio Canary 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-things, canary-deployment

I am trying to get started with Android Things. I am selecting Android Things in Project type in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 from May 26 2017.

[image]

My gradle build is failing.

[image]

What is wrong here? Is this an issue with the Canary build?

Comment: Canary 2 studio 3.0.is not yet stable released. Try by starting another new project and let me know!

Comment: I was able to fix this using the embedded jdk version. I have to use the Canary build since I am trying to play with the 'Android Things' and only the Canary build has that SDK included.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to answer my own questions but here I am, hope this helps someone. This issue was the JDK I was using. I was pointing to JDK 1.8 on my computer instead of using the embedded JDK in Android Studio, issue was resolved.